# SQL query to order by the difference between FIRST and BEST scores

Tags: optimization, performance, sql, mysql

Can anyone help me optimise this query?  I have the following table:

```
cdu_user_progress:
--------------------------------------------------------------
|id    |uid     |lesson_id    |game_id    |date    |score    |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

For each user, I'm trying to obtain the difference between the best and first scores for a particular game_id for a particular lesson_id, and order the results by that difference ('progress' in my query):

```sql
SELECT ms.uid AS id, ms.max_score - fs.first_score AS progress
FROM (
    SELECT up.uid, MAX(CASE WHEN game_id = 3 THEN score ELSE NULL END) AS max_score
    FROM cdu_user_progress up
    WHERE  (up.uid IN  ('1671', '1672', '1673', '1674', '1675', '1676', '1679', '1716', '1725',         '1726', '1937', '1964', '1996', '2062', '2065', '2066', '2085', '2086')) AND (up.lesson_id = '65') AND (up.score > '-1')
GROUP BY up.uid
) ms
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT up.uid, up.score AS first_score 
    FROM cdu_user_progress up
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT up.uid, MIN(CASE WHEN game_id = 3 THEN date ELSE NULL END) AS first_date
        FROM cdu_user_progress up
        WHERE  (up.uid IN  ('1671', '1672', '1673', '1674', '1675', '1676', '1679', '1716', '1725', '1726', '1937', '1964', '1996', '2062', '2065', '2066', '2085', '2086')) AND (up.lesson_id = '65') AND (up.score > '-1') 
        GROUP BY up.uid
    ) fd ON fd.uid = up.uid AND fd.first_date = up.date
) fs ON fs.uid = ms.uid
ORDER BY progress DESC
```

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ms.uid AS id
```

No effect on performance, but this seems weird.  You have a column in that table named `id`, but you are actually returning `uid` as `id`.  Why not just keep it as `uid`?

```
LEFT JOIN (
```

You know that the user has a score, because you found it in the first query.  Therefore, you don't need a `LEFT JOIN`.  A regular `INNER JOIN` is fine and will be considerably faster.

```
CASE WHEN game_id = 3 THEN date ELSE NULL END
```

It's not clear to me what this buys you.  Why not just put `up.game_id = 3` in the `WHERE` clause?  This will seriously confuse the optimizer.  Same thing for the `max_score` query.

Given this query, do you have an index on `lesson_id`, `game_id`, `uid`, `score`, `date`?  This query could hit only the index.  It's possible that `date` should be before `score`.  I'd try making it both ways and then running `EXPLAIN` to see which it hits.  Then you can delete the other.  You should put whichever of `lesson_id` and `game_id` has more potential values first.  It's possible that `uid` should go before either, but I'd have to test to see.

You put `score` and `date` last in the index because they have inequalities.  This keeps the query from being able to optimize later columns, so they go last.  In regards to the `uid IN` portion, I believe that it may be able to hold its place on the `game_id` and `lesson_id` pair, so I put `uid` after them.

```
SELECT ms.uid AS id, ms.max_score - fs.first_score AS progress
FROM (
    SELECT up.uid, MAX(score) AS max_score
    FROM cdu_user_progress up
    WHERE  up.uid IN  ('1671', '1672', '1673', '1674', '1675', '1676', '1679', '1716', '1725',         '1726', '1937', '1964', '1996', '2062', '2065', '2066', '2085', '2086') AND up.lesson_id = '65' AND up.score > '-1' AND up.game_id = 3
    GROUP BY up.uid
) ms
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT up.uid, up.score AS first_score 
    FROM cdu_user_progress up
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT up.uid, MIN(date) AS first_date
        FROM cdu_user_progress up
        WHERE up.uid IN  ('1671', '1672', '1673', '1674', '1675', '1676', '1679', '1716', '1725', '1726', '1937', '1964', '1996', '2062', '2065', '2066', '2085', '2086') AND up.lesson_id = '65' AND up.score > '-1' AND up.game_id = 3
        GROUP BY up.uid
    ) fd ON fd.uid = up.uid AND fd.first_date = up.date
    WHERE up.game_id = 3 AND up.lesson_id = '65'
) fs ON fs.uid = ms.uid
ORDER BY progress DESC
```

Note that I added `WHERE up.game_id = 3 AND up.lesson_id = '65'` because I think it will help the optimizer.  You should check the `EXPLAIN` plan to be sure.

Comment: Hi, the CASE part is to ensure I receive results for ALL up.uids, even if they are NULL...